# Как удалить символ перевода строки в конце файла?

Tags: файлы, linux

Здравствуйте. Есть набор текстовых файлов, сформированных командой >> $[var.txt](http://var.txt). Они состоят из одной строчки (ну ерунда такая, костыль) и автоматически добавленного символа перевода сроки. Этот символ нужно удалить, иначе файл не ищется командой egrep по регулярному выражению. Как его правильно обозначить для sed/awk ? \n не подходит :( . Раньше работал вот такой код

```
for fl in *.txt ; do if [ 'tail -c1 "$fl" | xxd -ps' = "0a" ] ; then head -c -1 "$fl" > tmp ; mv "tmp" "$fl" ; fi ; done
```

Работать он перестал. Буду рад любой подсказке.

Comment: А может так:

     perl -anpe chomp $fl >$$; mv $$ $fl

Comment: Вот для файлов, вида f1, f2 ... и результат (перввая строка без \\n) в f1.1l, f2.1l ...

    for i in f*; do a=`head -1 $i`; echo -n $a >$i.1l; done

Comment: Выражение $a >$i и создает проблему. Создается текстовый файл, в котором кроме содержимого переменной $a есть символ переноса строки. Его видно в leafpad, но в gedit уже не увидишь ) egrep отказывается искать такой файл ( используется регулярное выражение вида "^regexp$", убрать $ тоже нельзя, ищутся не те файлы ). После удаления переноса вручную и сохранения ( тот же leafpad ) файл становится не виден для egrep.

Comment: @Павел Данилишин, команды `>` самой по себе в природе не существует. `>` - это символ sh/bash/csh (и т.п.) программы, который переадресует stdout в файл.

На самом деле запись **без ньюлайна** обеспечивает **флаг -n** в команде `echo`, а `>` просто переключает вывод `echo` в файл.

--

А что реально-то не работает? В каком контексте?

Comment: Спасибо огромное.С флагом -n заработало. О флаге не знал ,познания в баше еще скудны, за просвещение спасибо. В скрипте нужно было организовать сохранение результатов операций где-то, с возможностью потом извлечь. Выбрал вариант хранить в простых текстовых файлах ( вместо массива ), но поиск по такой "базе данных" не получался. Еще раз спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@Павел Данилишин](/users/8839/%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD), пришлось в ответе, т.к. в комментарий не лезет.

Не понимаю, почему у Вас не работает. Смотрите

```
avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode/tst$ cat >f.txt
line 1
line 2
avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode/tst$ od -bc f.txt
0000000 154 151 156 145 040 061 012 154 151 156 145 040 062 012
          l   i   n   e       1  \n   l   i   n   e       2  \n
0000016
avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode/tst$ a=`head -1 f.txt`; echo -n $a >f.txt
avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode/tst$ od -bc f.txt
0000000 154 151 156 145 040 061
          l   i   n   e       1
0000006
avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode/tst$
```

После `echo -n $a >f.txt` никаких ньюлайнов. Вы флаг **-n** в `echo` не забыли?

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Именно его я и "забыл". Комментарий выше.